# Firefox Addon unable to get page DOM in pageMod content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on a Firefox addon using the Addon SDK in FF44.0a2 Developer Edition. 
I have a pageMod defined as so

```
var gmailPageMod = pageMod.PageMod({
include: "https://mail.google.com/*",
contentScriptWhen: "ready",
contentScriptFile: [self.data.url('js/jquery.js'), self.data.url('js/angular.min.js'), self.data.url('js/script.js')]
});
```

and I am trying to get the gmail page DOM in script.js. I have tried `document`, `window`, `unsafeWindow`, `window.content`, `window.document` but they all return either `null` or `undefined`, or log an empty Object `Object { }` in the browser console. The closest I got to seeing the gmail page DOM was by using `unsafeWindow.console.log(document)` but I'm unsure how to save the DOM in a variable/access it. `var unsafeDom = unsafeWindow.document` doesn't work either. I'd deeply appreciate any and all help on this matter.

Comment: have you tried without angular/jquery?

Comment: i kinda need to get the scope of the angular app which is also kinda a core part of the project so yeah.....

Comment: try to reduce your testcase to a simple script without those dependencies. after all those scripts could be messing with the available objects.

Comment: but i need the available objects after these dependencies have worked :(

Comment: Just to inform you, you can use `./foo.bar` instead of `self.data.url('foo.bar')`, it will still select `foo.bar` from the `/data` directory. Also, try adding just `script.js`, and inside that have some very simple code to test, like `console.log(document.innerHTML)`